# Flutter: detecting tap on multiple widgets

Tags: flutter, gesture

I have a Row of 4 buttons, what if I want to call a different callback (or same function with different arguments) on tap on every individual button and on every combination of buttons (simultaneously pressing two or more buttons).

I have no clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First you'll need to wrap each button with a `GestureDetector`, read more [about these here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/gestures)
2. You need a method,(_handleMultiTouch) to handle all the `onTapDown`,`onTapUp`and `onTapCancel` events.

   `onTapDown => _handleMultiTouch(..somebuttonId, the event)`
3. In `_handleMultiTouch(int id, var event)` is where you'll declare all the logic for handling multi touch. Here you'll save if user has tapped one or two button, or the user stopped a tap on button 1, etc. Use a switch or a if statment and save the touch states.